# with certain days range, events won't get rendered

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

Changing the view range with the following code, I get all events rendered, but for certain days range, the events won't get rendered.

With the following days range - 18,19,20 or 21 days, the events won't get rendered, otherwise all is ok for all type of ranges.

Inspecting the following object property:

```
$('#fullcalendar_scheduler').fullCalendar('getView').timeBodyScroller.canvas.width
```

I get `--> "",` instead of a positive width...

Any idea? Is there a known problem?

```
$('#fullcalendar_scheduler').fullCalendar('option', 'visibleRange', {
        start: new Date(startDate).yyyymmdd(),
        end: dateAdd(startDate, currentDurationCount, $('#zoom-scale-selector').val()).yyyymmdd(),
});
```

The following function gets start and end date, I will post also the dateAdd function:

```
function updateTimelineDuration(start_date, end_date) {
  if (typeof start_date === 'undefined' || start_date === null || start_date.length == 0) {
    start_date = $.trim($("#start_date").val()).substring(0, 10);
  }

  // If we have no 'start_date', from any source, don't do anything
  if (typeof start_date === 'undefined' || start_date === null || start_date.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  var startDate = new Date(start_date);

  if (typeof end_date === 'undefined' || end_date === null || end_date.length == 0) {
    end_date = dateAdd(startDate, currentDurationCount - 1, $('#zoom-scale-selector').val());
  }

  var endDate = new Date(end_date);

  var conversionDivisor;
  switch ($('#zoom-scale-selector').val()) {
    case 'month':
        // TODO: Fix me
        // 1 month (30 days) = 2592000000 ms
        conversionDivisor = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
        break;
    case 'week':
        // 1 week = 604800000 ms
        conversionDivisor = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
        break;
    case 'day':
    default:
        // 1 day =  86400000 ms
        conversionDivisor = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  }

  currentDurationCount = Math.round((endDate - startDate) / conversionDivisor) + 1;
  if (currentDurationCount < 1) { currentDurationCount = 1; }

  // Adjust timeline    
  $('#fullcalendar_scheduler').fullCalendar('changeView', 'timeline', new Date(startDate).yyyymmdd());
  $('#fullcalendar_scheduler').fullCalendar('option', 'visibleRange', {
    start: new Date(startDate).yyyymmdd(),
    end: dateAdd(startDate, currentDurationCount, $('#zoom-scale-selector').val()).yyyymmdd(),
  });
  $('#fullcalendar_scheduler').fullCalendar('render');
  // Update zoom-text
  $('#zoom-text').text(currentDurationCount);
}
```

Here is the dateAdd function:

```
function dateAdd(date, interval, units) {
    var ret = new Date(date); // don't change original date
    var checkRollover = function () { if (ret.getDate() != date.getDate()) ret.setDate(0); };
    switch (units.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'year': ret.setFullYear(ret.getFullYear() + interval); checkRollover(); break;
        case 'quarter': ret.setMonth(ret.getMonth() + 3 * interval); checkRollover(); break;
        case 'month': ret.setMonth(ret.getMonth() + interval); checkRollover(); break;
        case 'week': ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + 7 * interval); break;
        case 'day': ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + interval); break;
        case 'hour': ret.setTime(ret.getTime() + interval * 3600000); break;
        case 'minute': ret.setTime(ret.getTime() + interval * 60000); break;
        case 'second': ret.setTime(ret.getTime() + interval * 1000); break;
        default: ret = undefined; break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: this sounds very strange. Can you give us a runnable demo of your issue (e.g. CodePen or similar)? It's hard to visualise what you mean, and it's hard to understand what is happening, especially as we can't see all of the functions being referenced the your code shown above. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my issue.I can provide screenshots from the case when it works as expected, and screenshots when it does not. Will this help ?

Comment: yes, if you combine it with a more complete code example - we need enough code to be able to reproduce your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance

Comment: Difficult to prepare a running code. But the issue is in the above mentioned code.
ithe object has two properties:
1) $('#fullcalendar_scheduler').fullCalendar('getView').timeBodyScroller.canvas.width
2) $('#fullcalendar_scheduler').fullCalendar('getView').timeBodyScroller.canvas.minWidth
for the good cases property 1) has a positiv value and property 2) has "".
for the bad case, (18,19,20 & 21 events), 1) has "" and 2) has a positiv value. Somehow, in this code the values are switched...

Comment: ok I know that, but it's unclear, from that code, _why_ it is happening. It's not the expected behaviour in fullCalendar, obviously. It's not an issue you can see in any demos etc. Possibly it has to do with your visibleRange...but I can't see how you create the range, or what values are in it, because that code uses other functions from your code, and values from your page, none of which I can see right now. So it's impossible for me to reproduce your issue. If you can't / won't share further code for some reason, then it's impossible for me to help you unfortunately, even if I would like to.

Comment: it is not that I don't want, but to provide something running, it is too big.The mentioned code gets the start date and end date, then

Comment: it doesn't necessarily need to run, although that would be great. But it should at least be enough to have chance of recreating the problem. Work out which bits of your code are most important, and post enough that we could work out what it would do if we could run it. e.g. I can't run your visibleRange code or predict its result because I can't see your dateAdd() function code, I can't see the value or currentDurationCount or the value of $('#zoom-scale-selector').val() and I can't se your .yyyymmdd() function either (it seems to be a non-standard extension to the Date object)

Comment: You can use the "edit" button under your question to add more information and code. It would also help to see some sample event data as well. Thankyou.

Comment: How can I attach a file to a comment ?

Comment: I hope I didn't mess around with the texts... and you can read and get more idea of what I'm trying to do... Thank you.

Comment: Hi ADyson, were you able to read the code I have added (two functions) ?

Comment: is the information I have lately provided not helpful ?

Comment: Sorry, It's the weekend...there are other things to do :-). I'll take a closer look soon

Comment: I have found some interesting way to overcome the issue... when activating the devtool using chrome or microsoft edge, the problem is gone... deactivating the devtool problem is back... any idea/experience why ? Thank you. Dani

Comment: of course, my apology ( I thought you might look at it tomorrow or when ever you have time of course).

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. But what is still missing, and I mentioned before, is **data**. Can you give me sample values for `start_date` and `end_date` (as passed into updateTimelineDuration()`. And also a sample value for `$('#zoom-scale-selector').val()`. Can you please give a set of values where the calendar works ok, and a set of values which cause it to show the problem you're describing. Also the checkRollover() is still missing, so I can't run the dateAdd() function. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. your dateAdd function...it's great, but it's complicated! You know fullCalendar relies on momentJS, and they have all these kinds of functions ready-made and heavily tested and reliable? You could save yourself a lot of code testing and maintenance, since momentJS must already be included in your page. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/ for example

Comment: Here are some inputs to the updateTimelineDuration() in case of issue:
Start date:                     End date:
1) "2019-05-19 07:00"       "2019-06-05T07:00:00+02:00"
2) "2019-05-19 07:00"       "2019-06-06T07:00:00+02:00"
Input in case of no issue:
3) "2019-05-19 07:00"        "2019-06-04T07:00:00+02:00"
4) "2019-05-19 07:00"        "2019-06-14T07:00:00+02:00"

Comment: $('#zoom-scale-selector').val() is always --> "day"
The value of --> end: dateAdd(startDate, currentDurationCount, $('#zoom-scale-selector').val()).yyyymmdd() :
for 1) --> "2019-06-06"
for 2) --> "2019-06-07"
for 3) --> "2019-06-05"
for 4) --> "2019-06-15"

Comment: The checkRollover() is part of the addDate() function:
var checkRollover = function () { if (ret.getDate() != date.getDate()) ret.setDate(0); };

As I have mentioned in my latest message, I get the issue when I'm not activating the devtool (chrome). When devtool is active, I get no issue.

Let me know if you need further information and thank you so much for taking the time to look at issue.

Comment: oh sorry you're right it is. Thanks for the extra details. I'll have a look at it asap

Comment: One thing was still missing - the definition of the custom ".yyyymmdd()" on the Date object. But I can guess what it does, and replace it by using momentJS. So I made a little demo incorporating your code into a Scheduler instance, with some sample event data I invented. It starts showing a single day of the timeline. After two seconds I told it to automatically run `updateTimelineDuration( "2019-05-19 07:00", "2019-06-05T07:00:00+02:00");` (i.e. your example data number 1). You can view the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/v28sj5zd/1/

Comment: As you will see, it updates the view without any issue, and the events are displayed. I cannot reproduce the problem you've described. Clearly something is different between my environment and yours. Things I can imagine being a possibility, and which you can check and then inform me: 1) different version of fullCalendar and/or Scheduler, 2) something different in your event data which turns out to be important, 3) something different in your calendar options, 4) some custom CSS in your page clashing with the fullCalendar CSS. 5) the issue is actually in the missing .yyyymmdd() function

Comment: Let me know how you get on checking those out. You can always update the demo to better reflect your scenario, and then re-run it until you can reproduce the problem. That process in itself should help you to narrow down the possible causes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. At the moment I‘m on the roads, l‘ll try the suggestions as soon as possible. We are also moving to fullcallendar 4. I‘ll keep you informed.

Comment: Hi, sorry that it took me that long to give an update, but since updating to fullcalendar version 4, the issue is gone. No matter what date range we select, all gets rendered and visible.
Thank you again for your support.